# php is returning `500 Internal Server Error` instead of error reporting

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, php-7

PHP 7 on Ubuntu server 16 is always returning `500 Internal Server Error` without error explanation or reporting when there is any error. I tried to use

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);
```

but still does not work!

for example I removed `;` from a working php file and I got `500 Internal Server Error`.

I edited php.ini to include

```
 display_errors = On
 error_reporting= E_ALL
```

then restarted Apache without any success

Comment: I should see if there is something bad in '.htaccess'. But there could be other causes for a 500 error. For xample bad things in 'httpd.conf'

Comment: As I said I tried on a working file and removed `;` and no errors are reported just `500 status`

Comment: 500 iis a Server Error. Has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: It should be but with me that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: As @DeepakKumarTP answer: I edited display_errors directive on php.ini (/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini), and finally the 500 error page disappear, and the real error was displayed.